# List Category Posts not showing posts marked private to logged-in users

Tags: plugin-list-category-post, private

I'm using the List Category Posts plugin, and it isn't listing posts marked private, even if the appropriate user is logged in. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

List Category Posts plugin uses [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to actually get the posts and its default post_status is publish and that is way you won't get any private posts.

To "Fix" it you can edit the file named include/CatList.php of the plugin and add

```
$lcp_query .= '&post_status=private';
```

before line 51 before

```
$this->lcp_categories_posts = get_posts($lcp_query);
```

this will get you only private posts and to really "FIX" it you need to add this code:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    parse_str( $lcp_query, $lcp_query );
    $lcp_query['post_status'] = array('publish','private');
}
```

on line 51 again before

```
$this->lcp_categories_posts = get_posts($lcp_query);
```

and offer the author of the plugin this as a patch so the next time he updates you want lose this fix.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer! I'll add this into the next release of List Category Plugins. Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: @Fernando: Glad i can help.

Comment: Thanks @Bainternet! And thanks @Fernando for making this great plugin.